# Laravel array validation old values

Tags: validation, laravel-5

Using Laravel 5.4 I have a form with array inputs called: coffee_kg_bags

In my form:

```
<input type="text" name="kg_bags[{{$cof->id}}]" value="{{ old('kg_bags.' .$cof->id) }}">
```

In my controller I do all kinds of validations and I get an error, but I don't get the old value in the form.

I entered 2 values on fields:
$cof->id = 1 and $cof->id = 2

I get an error on the field with $cof->id = 1 but I don't get the old values.

In the update method in the controller:

```
dd(Input::get('kg_bags.2'));
```

Gives the value I entered

But:
    dd(Input::old('kg_bags.2'));

Gives null.

```
dd(Input::old());
```

Gives an empty array

Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    dd($request->old);
```

Instead

```
dd(Input::old());
```

Comment: I'm doing it in the controller why would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @phpdroid I did this in my form:

```
<input type="text" name="kg_bags[{{$cof->id}}]" value="{{ Request::old('kg_bags.' . $cof->id) }}">
```